# Plot solution of an integral with parameter

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, physics

In [this article](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1674-1137/ac67fe/pdf), they solve the following integral
$$ \mathcal{I}_{o b s}\left(\nu_0\right)=\int_{\gamma_i} \frac{(A(r))^{3 / 2}}{r^2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{A(r)}+r^2\left(\frac{d \varphi}{d r}\right)^2} d r $$

where
$$ A(r)=1-\frac{2 M r^2}{\left(g^2+r^2\right)^{3 / 2}} $$
$$  \left( \frac{d \varphi}{d r} \right)^2 = \frac{1}{r^4} \left( \frac{1}{b^2} - \frac{A(r)}{r^2} \right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{r^2} \left( \frac{b^2}{r^2 - A(r) b ^2} \right) $$
so
$$ I_{obs} (\nu_0) = \int_{\gamma_i} \frac{\left( A(r) \right)^{3/2}}{r^2} \sqrt{ \frac{1}{A(r)} + \frac{b^2}{r^2 - A (r) b^2} } d r $$

and when evaluating the path of the photon, they obtain a result as a function of b that when graphed is (for $g = 0$ and $M = 1$ we have the curve in black)

[image]

So I wrote the following in wolfram mathematica

```
ClearAll;

M = 1;

g = 0;

A[r_] := 1 - (2 M r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2);

Arm[r_] := (A[r])^(3/2)/r^2 Sqrt[1/A[r] + (b^2/(r^2 - A[r] b^2))];

Simplify[ToRadicals[Integrate[Arm[r], r, Assumptions -> r > 0 && b > 0]]]
```

we have

[image]

I named the above $F \left[ r, b \right]$$ and evaluated the integral separately as follows

```
FF[b_] := F[100, b] - F[2.4, b]
```

This is because when I try to evaluate it when doing the integral, it does not give me results and they keep executing. When graphing, I get a part of the graph I want to get

```
Plot[FF[b], {b, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Could you give me any suggestions on how to optimize the routine to be able to evaluate and graph the result on the line where it is integrated? Any suggestion or observation is welcome.

**Update**
In the case of falling spherical accretion flow, the intensity is (eq. 24)
$$ I_{o b s} \left(v_0^{i} \right) \propto \int_{\gamma_i} \frac{g_i^3 k_t d r}{r^2\left|k_r\right|} $$

$$ g_i=\left(u_e^t+\left(\frac{\mathcal{K}_r}{\mathcal{K}_t}\right) u_e^r\right)^{-1} $$

$$\mathcal{K}_t=\frac{1}{b}, \quad \frac{\mathcal{K}_r}{\mathcal{K}_t}= \pm \sqrt{B(r)\left(\frac{1}{A(r)}-\frac{b^2}{r^2}\right)}$$

$$ B(r) = 1/A(r) $$

$$ u_e^t=A(r)^{-1}, \quad u_e^r=-\sqrt{\frac{1-A(r)}{A(r) B(r)}}, \quad u_e^\theta=u_e^{\varphi}=0 $$

In Mathematica, I wrote:

```
Clear[Int]; M = 1;
A[r_] := 1 - (2 M r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2);
uet = 1/A[r];
uer = -Sqrt[1 - A[r]];
kt = 1/b;
kr = kt/A[r] Sqrt[1 - (A[r] b^2)/r^2];
gi = (uet + kr/kt uer)^-1;
in = (gi^3/r^2) (kt/kr) // Simplify ;
Int[bt_?NumericQ, gt_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[in /. {b -> bt, g -> gt}, {r, 2, 100}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10]
g0 = {0, .475, .75};
Plot[Evaluate[Int[b, #] & /@ g0 // Re], {b, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Red}, AxesLabel -> {b, Subscript[I, obs]}]
```

However, I do not get the expected graph (Figure 5 in the paper) instead:

[image]

And the graph I am looking to obtain is

[image]

Comment: Oerhaps it helps to do the integral in 2 pieces, one up to the cusp and then starting agin from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $\frac {d\phi}{dr}$ and `Ueff` from the paper we have

```
M = 1; L = 1;

A[r_] := 1 - (2 M r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2); Veff = 
 1/r^2 (1 - 2 M r^2/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2)); dphidr2 = 
 L^2/r^4/(1/b^2 - Veff);

in = (A[r])^(3/2)/r^2 Sqrt[1/A[r] + r^2 dphidr2] // Simplify
```

For this expression it could be better to use numerical integration in a form

```
 Int[b_?NumericQ,g_?NumericQ] := 
     NIntegrate[((1 - (2 r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2))^(3/2) Sqrt[
 1/(r^2 (1/b^2 - 1/r^2 + 2/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2))) + 1/(
  1 - (2 r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2))])/r^2, {r, 2, 100}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

Visualization

```
g0 = {0, .475, .75}; Plot[
 Evaluate[Int[b, #] & /@ g0 // Re], {b, 0, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Red}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"b", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(obs\)]\)"}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.2}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Figure 1]

It looks similar but not exactly the same as in the paper. Maybe we should play with parameters like integration limits `{r, 2, 100}` and `L`.

**Update 1** To reproduce Figure 4 from the [paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1674-1137/ac67fe/pdf) we use code

```
Int[b_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[((1 - (2 r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2))^(3/2) Sqrt[
    1/(r^2 (1/b^2 - 1/r^2 + 2/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2))) + 1/(
     1 - (2 r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2))])/r^2, {r, 2, 100}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4]//Quiet
g0 = {0, .475, .75}; ParallelTable[
 DensityPlot[
  Evaluate[Re[Int[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], g]]], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"g/M = ", g}], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 150, 
  PlotRange -> All], {g, g0}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

**Update 2.** To compute Figure 5 from the paper we use code

```
Clear[Int]; M = 1;
A[r_] := 1 - (2 M r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2); B[r_] := 1/A[r];
uet = 1/A[r];
uer = -Sqrt[1 - A[r]];
kt = 1/b;
kr = -kt  Sqrt[B[r] (1/A[r] - b^2/r^2)];
gi = kt/(kt uet + kr uer);
in = (gi^3/r^4) (kt/(kr^2)^.5);
Int[bt_?NumericQ, gt_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[in /. {b -> bt, g -> gt}, {r, 2., 100}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8]
g0 = {0, .475, .75};
Plot[Evaluate[Int[b, #] & /@ g0 // Abs], {b, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Red}, 
 AxesLabel -> {b, Subscript[I, obs]}, PlotPoints -> 150]
```

[image: Figure3]

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for all the clarification. I don't have much experience with Mathematica. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: hi, I'm trying to obtain the two-dimensional intensity map (Fig. 4 in the article) from the results you gave me, however, I still can't get it. Could you give me any suggestions if possible? Likewise, I found in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.12074.pdf) (page 8) that the intensity is circularly symmetric, with the impact parameter $b$ of the radius, which satisfies $$b^2 = x^2 + y^2$$ but I can't think of how to implement it

Comment: @Soliton-104 Please, see Update 1 to my answer.

Comment: Wow, Again, thank you very very very much!

Comment: I'm trying to get the intensity graph of the descending spherical accretion flow and wrote an update on my question. I haven't figured out what my mistake is for almost a week so it would mean a lot if you can take a look and give me some suggestions. However, please also excuse my insistence on this question. @AlexTrounev

Comment: @Soliton-104 In this case we need to compute trajectories of light rays shown in Figure 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand why solving the trajectories in Figure 1 would contribute to the intensity plot for the downward spherical accretion flow case. Could you guide me a little more please?

Comment: @Soliton-104 Please, pay attention that they defined integral in (17) and (24) along photon path $\gamma_i$, and not on `{r, 2, 100}`  as we used for simplicity.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand. I understand that the photon comes from infinity to the photon sphere, which is where the intensity is greatest. For radii smaller than the photon sphere, the photon is absorbed, so you would expect that for $b = 0$ the intensity is approximately zero. On the other hand, wouldn't integrating over the path of the photon be analogous to integrating along the proper differential length (eq. 23)? So, I thought it would be nice to consider the integration interval from 2 to 100

Comment: @Soliton-104 If so, then see Update 2 to my answer. :)