# Intensity pattern

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, physics

I'm trying to get the following intensity pattern from [this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/ab518c/pdf)

[image]

In the Newtonian case, the equations for the intensity (eq. 9 and 10 in the article), I put them in Mathematica with the change $b^2 = x^2 + y^2$ because the intensity is circularly symmetric with the parameter impact $b$ as radius (page 8 in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.12074.pdf))

```
H[x_, y_] := 10^3 1/(32 \[Pi] (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^3);
G[x_, y_] := 10^3 (1/(32 \[Pi]^2 (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^3)) ArcTan[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/Sqrt[4 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2]] -10^3 Sqrt[4 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2]/(128 \[Pi]^2 (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2);
combinedFunction[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{G[x, y], x^2 + y^2 < 2}, {H[x, y], x^2 + y^2 > 2}}] 
DensityPlot[combinedFunction[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Exclusions -> All,PlotPoints -> 100, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

and I get

[image]

However, it does not look like the image in the article. Could anyone advise me or give me a suggestion? You should obtain a circumference of radius $2$ as in the paper. I'm also trying to get the intensity pattern for a more general case where numerical integration was performed (I actually asked the [question here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292214/plot-solution-of-an-integral-with-parameter/292224?noredirect=1#comment725934_292224)) but I can't find how to make the change $b^2 = x^2 + y^2$. I appreciate suggestions or observations

Comment: Your plot is only showing a range up to ~0.2, and showing everything above that as white. Add `PlotRange -> {0, 1.2}`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the `combinedFunction` be `Piecewise[{{G[x, y], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 2}, {H[x, y], 
   Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] > 2}}]`?

Comment: @MelaGo You're right. I honestly didn't notice that detail. Thank you so much!